# Find duplicates from array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array of objects in PHP like:

```
[
{
    "id": 99961,
    "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125275,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667995574207
},
{
    "id": 99960,        
    "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125274,
            "firstName": "CHRISTIAN",
            "lastName": "NEILS"               
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667986477133
},
{
    "id": 99959,
     "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125273,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667985600420
},
{
    "id": 99958,
     "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125275,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667985600420
},
]
```

I want to find duplicates based on same `candidate` firstName and lastName but different `candidate` id's.
I have tried multiple methods like array_search, array_column, array_filter etc but nothing giving desired result.
Output should be array of `candidate.data.id` that are different but with same `firstName` and `lastName`.
Can anyone guide me in building the algorithm?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @fubar Output could be candidate ids

Comment: Please [edit] your question body to explicitly state the required output.

Comment: @MahaWaqar Put your expected output in the question so we can answer properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "different IDs?" Each record in your example contains two IDs: the topmost `.id` key, and `.candidate.data.id`. If all you want to do is compare `firstName` and `lastName`, then what do any of the IDs have to do with it?

Comment: @Maha You still haven't showed us your exact desired result, please [edit] once more to show us which `id` you want to use.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Group on a key which is composed of the candidate's first name and last name and push the respective id as a child of that group using the id as the key and the value -- this ensures uniqueness within the group.

Then filter out the candidates that only occur once and re-index the qualifying subsets.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FVfM4))

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $compositeKey = "{$row['candidate']['data']['firstName']} {$row['candidate']['data']['lastName']}";
    $grouped[$compositeKey][$row['candidate']['data']['id']] = $row['candidate']['data']['id'];
}
$result = [];
foreach ($grouped as $id => $group) {
    if (count($group) > 1) {
        $result[$id] = array_values($group);
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'Jose Zayas' => 
  array (
    0 => 125275,
    1 => 125273,
  ),
)
```

Or with one loop, collect all unique ids per group then push all keys into the result array if more than 1 total in the group. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/idLuh))

```
$duplicated = [];
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $compositeKey = "{$row['candidate']['data']['firstName']} {$row['candidate']['data']['lastName']}";
    $id = $row['candidate']['data']['id'];
    $grouped[$compositeKey][$id] = '';
    if (count($grouped[$compositeKey]) > 1) {
        $duplicated[$compositeKey] = array_keys($grouped[$compositeKey]);
    }
}
var_export($duplicated);
```

Comment: But this is also returning records with same id's. I just need records with different id's. See my edited question json @mickmackusa

Comment: I appreciate. Just try your answer with the edited json I gave in my question. You will understand what I am trying to say

Comment: Fixed it now @Maha

Answer (score -1):

You need to set iteration for to pick key data (firstName and lastName) for buffer. After it, you can check key from buffer data for to find exists users. :

```php
<?php

$arr = <<<JSON
[
{
    "id": 99959,
     "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125273,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667985600420
},
{
    "id": 99961,
    "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125275,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667995574207
},
{
    "id": 99960,        
    "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125274,
            "firstName": "CHRISTIAN",
            "lastName": "NEILS"               
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667986477133
},
{
    "id": 99958,
     "candidate": {
        "data": {
            "id": 125275,
            "firstName": "Jose",
            "lastName": "Zayas"           
        }
    },
    "dateAdded": 1667985600420
}
]
JSON;

$candidatePersonality = $exits = [];
$json = json_decode($arr,true);

array_walk($json,function($item,$key) use(&$candidatePersonality,&$exits){

    $userKey = $item['candidate']['data']['firstName'].' '.$item['candidate']['data']['lastName'];
    
    if(!isset($candidatePersonality[$userKey]) || (isset($candidatePersonality[$userKey]) && !in_array( $item['candidate']['data']['id'],$candidatePersonality[$userKey]))){
        
       $candidatePersonality[$userKey][] = $item['candidate']['data']['id'];

        if(count($candidatePersonality[$userKey])> 1){
            $exits[$userKey] = $candidatePersonality[$userKey];
        } 
    }
    
    
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($exits);
```

Comment: This "try this" answer is missing its educational explanation.  I do not endorse abusing `array_map()` as an iterator while ignoring its return data.  If you don't want its returned payload, then `array_walk()` is more appropriate.  When your returned payload may have a different number of values than the input array, then often `array_reduce()` is the most appropriate.  I like that this approach makes one cycle over the data, but it is potentially rewriting `$exits[$userKey]` over and over as it grows.

Comment: @mickmackusa can you show what are you suggesting?

Comment: @mickmackusa i changed. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov I need candidates with different id's. Your code also returning the same ones

Comment: I changed my conde. It seems , you want first ID keys. Check it.

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov I really appreciate your help. I need different candidate keys with same firstName and lastName. For say; I need output from my json in question ; [125275,125273]

Comment: Okay wait my answer bro.

Comment: I understood that, you need to response like your json format. Okay ?

Comment: Or you need just ids?  Like that : [125275,125273]

Comment: Output format doesn't matter much. Just need candidate with same firstName, lastName but with different id. Please see json in my question again. @TuralRzaxanov

Comment: Bro my answer will return you format: Array
(
    [Jose Zayas] => Array
        (
            [0] => 125275
            [1] => 125273
        )

)  Is it okay?

Comment: @TuralRzaxanov its perfect

Comment: Just give me result with different candidate id's

Comment: Bro can you write concrete result example ?

Comment: Notice how `125275` occurs twice within the `Jose Zayas` group in Maha's edited sample input.  Maha only wants to see `125275` once in the group, not twice.

Comment: Okay i will change

Comment: I changed answer. Now, we can see once item which is repeating name and lastnames.

Comment: Your script is not returning the unique results: https://3v4l.org/9hlW7

Comment: I changed my answer. This will return only once repeating candidates:  https://3v4l.org/Qd9ek but if you want only ids look for this:  https://3v4l.org/qsCak

Comment: You should update your answer so that it generates the desired result.

Comment: I updated my answer a long time ago

Comment: Okay, well, then I should inform you that it fails under different input -- https://3v4l.org/OD0X2  and here because of the order of the entries https://3v4l.org/Xk9Pp There are duplicated ids in the result array in both scenarios.  This answer is not reliable.

Comment: Okay... I have understood ( I changed my answer.